# How to get key of the maximum value present In a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to get the key of the maximum value (datatype can be anything like int/float).
The input json(dict) is :

```
fruits = {
  "Apple": {
    "0": 0
  },
  "Mango": {
    "0": 1
  }
}
```

but while returning the response using this piece of code:

```
fruits_value = max(float(v['0']) for k,v in fruits.items())
fruits_key = max(fruits.keys(), key=lambda x: fruits[x]['0'])
fruits_dict= {
fruits_key : fruits_value
}
return fruits_dict
```

I am getting below error :

```
Failed to test real-time endpoint
'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

the output should be something like :

```
{'Mango': 1.0}
```

Comment: You didn't include `fruits` as a [mre]. According to the error it's a string so it's not what you present here

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get value and key separately using two iterations. Just give it a `key=` argument and then you'll get the whole item back(a tuple actually - since we used `.items()`). You can then extract whatever you want:

```py
fruits = {
    "Apple": {"0": 0},
    "Mango": {"0": 1},
}

max_ = max(fruits.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["0"])
result = {max_[0]: max_[1]["0"]}
print(result)
```

output:

```
{'Mango': 1}
```

Comment: Alternative: `max_key = max(fruits, key=lambda x: fruits[x]["0"]) ; result = {max_key: fruits[max_key]['0']}`